# How to find the version of installed library in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, clang, python-import, llvm-clang

How can I find the version of clang installed on my system.

Link to clang lib: [(click!)](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/bindings/python/clang/cindex.py)

I want functionality like:

```
if libclang.version < 3.4:  
    print('Clang version not supported.')
```

or some other logic so that I can find the version of clang.

There is no `__version__` attribute in clang module. So I cannot do

```
if libclang.__version__ < 3.4
    print('Clang version not supported.')
```

Comment: You tried `import clang` and `dir(clang)`? (To see if there is sth resembling `index` method)

Comment: To get the C compiler version used to build Python, you can do something like `import re, sys; cc = re.search('\[(.*)\]', sys.version).group(1); print(cc)`.

Comment: @jjj Yes the result is: 
`['__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']`

Comment: @jmd_dk I need to find version of clang lib not the version of C compiler used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from pkg_resources import get_distribution

if get_distribution('libclang-py3').version != '3.4.0':
    logging.error('clang version not supported')
```

`get_distribution('pkg_name').version` will return the version of the installed package, but this might not work in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to get all installed libraries is `>>pip list`

Answer (score 1):

If you're unable to get the version of any packages directly, you can execute

> pip freeze | grep clang

in your script and in order to get execute this script, you can use subprocess module of python as mentioned below:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(["pip", "freeze", "|", "grep", "clang"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.communicate()[0].splitlines()
```

this will return all packages installed along with their packages and there you can have clang version.